# Is there a place near Miami, Florida where I can get close to wild animals without leaving my car?

Tags: camping, animals, disability-options

My husband and I love animals. All of our vacations are planned around opportunities for viewing wildlife, birds, marine animals, farm animals, backyard animals, butterflies, insects, and just about any other form of life.  I'm disabled and can't walk far, so we tailor our trips to places with handicapped accessibility and limited movement requirements.

A local friend in Massachusetts told me she heard of a drive-through wild animal nature preserve in Florida. Animals from many different regions of the world live there, and apparently most of them are loose. For the sake of safety, no pedestrians or other vehicles are allowed, just passenger cars with windows which can be kept closed. It sounds perfect for us!

The drive-though area is one section of a large park and campground.

She thinks it's a few hours north of Miami, Florida. Does anyone know the name of the place to which she's referring, including location and additional information about other things to do in the park?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like [Lion Country Safari](https://www.lioncountrysafari.com/) matches your description. From their front page:

> Florida’s only drive-through safari and walk-through amusement park invites you to spend the day on safari with over 900 animals. With animal displays and encounters, animal feeding experiences, 5 rides, water sprayground, food, shopping and more, you are sure to have a memorable experience at Lion Country Safari.

Comment: That's definitely it Greg. Thanks so much! Here are some details to supplement your answer.  It's a 300 acre full nature preserve, with an emphasis on conservation and education. The facilities other than the drive through section are wheelchair accessible, and wheelchairs are available for rent. There are 200 camping sites, including tent spots and rustic cabins. There's a pond for boating and fishing. I recommend a look around the website for anyone who loves both the outdoors and animals!